# back button callback function failing, or not firing, under particular condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm trying to manipulate the anchor element (#backButton), so that it fires a JS function on click. It works as it should except in the instance of clicking through the following element chain: #openShow > #openDetailsFromShow > #backButton > #backButton

On this final #backButton click the expected JS function ( closeShowProvider() ) does not fire, but instead #backButton reverts to its default behaviour.

I've tried searching for a solution to this, but I'm afraid my understanding of the issue is limiting my ability to resolve it. I suspect it may have something to do with closures, but I could be very wrong...

JSFiddle of the (not quite) working code https://jsfiddle.net/timothyvictor/u1dv83a1/2/

I'm really stuck on this and would very grateful for any help and/or pointers. Many thanks in advance,

TV

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<a id="backButton" href="#link">Back Button</a>
<input type="text" id="link">
<br>
<button onclick="openShowProvider('id', 'searchProviders.php')" id="openShow">Open Show Provider</button>
<br>
<button onclick="openProviderDetails('NEW', 'searchProviders.php')" id="openDetailsDirect">Open Provider Details Direct</button>
<br>
<button onclick="openProviderDetails('NEW', 'showProvider.php')" style="display:none" id="openDetailsFromShow"> Open Provider Details from Show Provider</button>
<br>
<div id="showProvider" style="display: none;">
    <h1 class="text-center">Show Provider is OPEN!!!!</h1>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-success" id="providerDetails" style="display: none;">
    <h1 class="text-center">Provider Details is OPEN!!!!</h1>
</div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
    function backButton (backFunc, param) {
$('#backButton').unbind().click(function(e){ //using unblind to clear backFunc before binding new event?
    e.preventDefault();
    backFunc(param);
    $(this).unbind('click');
});
}

function openShowProvider(id, return_page){
    if (return_page === 'searchProviders.php') {
        $('#showProvider, #openDetailsFromShow').show();
        $('#openShow, #openDetailsDirect').hide();
    }
    backButton(closeShowProvider, return_page);
}

function openProviderDetails(id, return_page) {
    if (return_page === 'searchProviders.php') {
        $('#openShow, #openDetailsDirect').hide();
    }
    if (return_page === 'showProvider.php') {
        $('#showProvider, #openDetailsFromShow').hide();
    }
    $('#providerDetails').show();
    backButton(closeProviderDetails, return_page);

}

function closeShowProvider(return_page){
    if (return_page === 'searchProviders.php' || return_page === 'providerDetails.php'){
        $('#showProvider, #openDetailsFromShow').hide();
        $('#openShow, #openDetailsDirect').show();
    }
}

function closeProviderDetails(return_page) {
    $('#providerDetails').hide();
    if (return_page === 'searchProviders.php'){
        $('#openShow, #openDetailsDirect').show();
    }
    if (return_page === 'showProvider.php') {
        $('#showProvider, #openDetailsFromShow').show();
        backButton(closeShowProvider, 'providerDetails.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: try to post an live example on JsFiddle or jsbin and post your question on the top of the question, or at least a short question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Hugo. JsFiddle posted and question moved to top.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi Hope it will solve your problem, there was some error while attaching and removing the click event

jsfiddle.net/u1dv83a1/3/

In this i have used the same code what you have used, but just changed the backButton pressed function in that

Comment: A link to jsfiddle with no explanation is not very helpful

Comment: Thanks, i have just updated the same jsFiddle what he has created, and in the explanation i have already written that there was some error while attaching and removing the click event

Comment: Thanks Mukesh. It seems that replacing unbind() with off('click') did the trick as well as removing the $(this).unbind('click'); Did you understand this from inspecting the code, or some other means of debugging? Thanks all the same.

Comment: Main issue was with the inner unbind, it will work with bind and unbind also